# Create table from txt file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datatables

I have a .txt file that looks just like a table with multiple rows and even more columns, this is just an example:

```
FRU          LPP      BOARD                      BO  QU  CT (TX/dBm)  VSP (RyL)   RX (dBm) UEs/RLs
RR           B_20     RB7                        A  11  -     -       1,31 18    2.9    -/-    
RT           B_21     RB7                        B  11  -     -       1,09 3     2.1    20/-
```

I'm interested in extracting data from a specific column.
It feels like i've tried everything with Pandas read_csv function but i have not been able to get results, it seems like an easy task but i'm really stuck here

```
Columns_from_txt = VA.partition('\n')[0].split()[0:-2] #extracting top row to be my columnames
Row_from_txt = VA.split('\n')[2:-2] #extracting all rows  
df = pd.read_csv(Row_from_txt, names=Columns_from_txt)
print(df['BOARD'])
```

This is just the latest example from all that i've tried, i dont know what else to do than to reach out to you guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, now with creating the dataframe from string:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = StringIO("""FRU          LPP      BOARD                      BO  QU  CT (TX/dBm)  VSP (RyL)   RX (dBm) UEs/RLs
RR           B_20     RB7                        A  11  -     -       1,31 18    2.9    -/-    
RT           B_21     RB7                        B  11  -     -       1,09 3     2.1    20/-    """)

df = pd.read_csv(text, delimiter=r"\s+")
```

**Output:**

```
    FRU     LPP     BOARD   BO  QU  CT  (TX/dBm)    VSP     (RyL)   RX  (dBm)   UEs/RLs
0   RR      B_20    RB7     A   11  -   -           1,31    18      2.9 -/-     NaN
1   RT      B_21    RB7     B   11  -   -           1,09    3       2.1 20/-    NaN
```

and `print(df["BOARD"])`:

```
0    RB7
1    RB7
Name: BOARD, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you Marco! Your answer gave me some clarity.
This works if i take the input directly from a textfile but not if my textfile is stored as a string.
i've tried with StringIO but it seems like StringIO cant handle INT and STR at the same time

Comment: I've updated it, it worked with `StringIO`. Could you check?

Comment: Thanks, yes it works when I read all the lines of a textfile with just my table in to a stringvariable and then with StringIO. but in my case I have a .txt file with ~5000 rows and with regex and patterns I'll find this peace that I want to create a table from, something is happening along the way when i want to store it as a string and i dont know what but i have taken another approach and gotten it to work, thanks to you!